# Python encoding text from RSS using feedparser

Tags: python, encoding, rss, feedparser

I'm trying to parse data from a RSS feed using feedparser module.

```
import feedparser

def main():
    try:
        rss = feedparser.parse('http://s.stooq.pl/rss/n.rss')
        print(rss.entries[0].title)

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
main()
```

which gives me following output:

*'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)*

I tried to change the encoding to UTF-8, however it results in this:

**b'Zostaniemy obs\xc5\x82u\xc5\xbceni w ka\xc5\xbcdym urz\xc4\x99dzie skarbowym'**
so this seems to be bytes literal.

What should I do with this string to display it properly ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming property `title` is a string, you can try:

```
print(rss.entries[0].title.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it resulted in : b'Zostaniemy obs\xc5\x82u\xc5\xbceni w ka\xc5\xbcdym urz\xc4\x99dzie skarbowym'

Comment: What's even stranger - when I run this code with your suggestion in Python2.7 - it works. Python3 still returns bytes string.

Comment: Yeah, my solution is for python 2.7.x

Comment: Just to make it clear. What would be the solution in Python 3 ?